# How to deploy a react app on azure using publish profile with Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, publish-profiles

How to deploy a react app on azure using publish profile with Visual Studio Code

deploy a react app on azure using publish profile with Visual Studio Code.
I have a publish profile and want to deploy the React/Nextjs app on azure using visual studio code editor.

Do I need any subscription or permission for this

Comment: Yes, you need to have an active Azure Subscription to create a resource and deploy the app to Azure App Service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need any subscription or permission for this

Yes, to deploy the Application to `Azure` you need to have an active Subscription  `Azure Account`.

- Install the `Azure App service` extension from the Extensions tab.

[image]

- Once you got the subscription, login to the Azure Account.

[image]

- Once you login to Azure, you can see all the available resources under your subscription.

[image]

- You need to have one resource group created.
- Need to deploy your react app to that resource.

Click on  `ctrl+shift+P` => select `Create New WebApp` and continue with next steps.

[image]

For more information refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-publish-webapp-app-service-vs-code/5-exercise-publish-app-azure-app-service-vs-code?pivots=nodeexpress) which explains the same.